# instantiateViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am having the following setup:

- Login Screen -> after successfully logging in, a new view will be initiated
- TabBarController -> attached to 4 different ViewControllers
- MenuViewController -> this is the starting point of the 4 tabbars

I want to initiate the MenuViewController + the tabbar on bottom programmatically like this:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Employee", bundle: nil)
   let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
   self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Unfortunately instead of initiating the view, simply nothing happens. 
Any ideas?

Comment: where you put above code

Comment: @Sh_Khan in a function that triggers if loginButton was clicked. It is definetly executed, checked this prior to asking

Comment: Provide more informations, how do You call this code exactly (it is important even if u know that code is executed cuz right now we don't even know what self objct is). What version of Xcode do you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Bozzo Game's comment, I have been able to find the solution to this problem.

The line 
   `self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)`

has to be replaced with

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tabbarVC
```

As the idea here was not to use `present` to display the tabbarVC on top of the current one, but to change the rootViewController of the Window.